# Add binding required tag dynamically go-gin

Tags: json, go, binding, go-gin

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
}
```

Is there a way to add

```
binding:"required"
```

to `json:"name"` without hardcoding it?

Comment: No, not to the type `Person`. You can create a new, anonymous struct dynamically with the `reflect` package however, and you could use the `Person` type as a "template" for that.

Comment: ... example for the comment above: https://play.golang.org/p/rj_H3lPXtIS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can dynamical  overwrite the struct in your handle function, and original Person struct remains unchanged .   Like this :

```golang
func HandleSomething(c *gin.Context) {

    type person struct {
        Person 
        Name string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
     }

     var p person
    if err = c.ShouldBind(&p); err != nil {
        err = errors.Wrap(util.ErrParams, err.Error())
       return
    }
    response = util.BuildResponse(middleware.PassCode, "Success", list)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)
    return
}
```